# Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename ./plugin.min.css

Tags: javascript, css, webpack

I get this error when I build webpack:

ERROR in chunk plugin.min [entry]
./plugin.min.css
Conflict: Multiple chunks emit assets to the same filename ./plugin.min.css (chunks 0 and 1)

Here is my **webpack.config.js** file:

```
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const debug = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production';
const webpack = require('webpack');

var extractBlockSCSS = new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
  filename: "./plugin.min.css",
})

var plugins = [
    extractBlockSCSS
];

var scssConfig = [
    {
        loader: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' ? 'style-loader' : MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
    }, 
    {
      loader: 'css-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    },
    {
      loader: 'sass-loader',
      options: {
        sourceMap: true
      }
    }
];

var config = {
    context: __dirname,
    devtool: debug ? 'inline-sourcemap' : false,
    mode: debug ? 'development' : 'production',
    entry: {
        'plugin.min': './resources/js/entry.js',
        'blocks.build': './resources/blocks/blocks.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname + '/dist/',
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'babel-loader'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                use: scssConfig
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: plugins
};

module.exports = (env, argv) => {
    return config;
};
```

I am guessing this is because I am using the same extract block filename? I have multiple entry points so not sure if that could cause the error I am seeing. Do I need to add more css file names/mini css extract plugins?

Answer (score 3):

Try this using ***mini-css-extract-plugin***

```
new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: "[name]/../style.css"
}),
```

Comment: Note that the issue is being solved by adding `[name]` to the filename property. It will be replaced with name defined in the Webpack entry property dynamically thus preventing multiple Webpack entries from emitting to the same file. In this case the path will be dynamic but something like `filename: '[name].css'` could be used as well.

Comment: Note: this causes "Error: Prevent writing to file that only differs in casing or query string from already written file."